# How to config child state in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes

Now I am trying to use stateProvider to nest views. But didn't work out. 
JS code:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('accountsetting',{
    url: '/account', 
    templateUrl: 'settings/account.html'
  })
  .state('accountsetting.security', {
    url: '/security', 
    templateUrl: 'settings/security/security.html'
  })
  .state('accountsetting.personalinformation', {
    url: '/personalinfo', 
    templateUrl: 'settings/personalinfo/personal-information.html'
  })
  .state('accountsetting.receiptemails', {
    url: '/emails', 
    templateUrl: 'settings/receiptemail/receipt-email.html'
  })
  .state('accountsetting.personalcard', {
    url: '/personalcards', templateUrl: 'submitter/PersonalCard/Personalcard.html'
  });
```

index.html:

```
    <ul>
     <li><a ui-sref='accountsetting'>account</a></li>
     <li><a ui-sref='reports'>Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view></div>
```

account.html:

```
<div class='seetingtabs'>
        <ul>
            <li><a ui-sref='accountsetting.personalinformation'>Personal Information</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref='accountsetting.security'>Security</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref='accountsetting.receiptemails'>Receipt Emails</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref='accountsetting.personalcard'>Personal Cards</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

I can access the account page from index page, but I I can't access the child state of accountsetting, the ui-view of account.html doesn't work for me.

Comment: Seems ok to me. Are you sure your template URLs are correct?

Comment: Try setting the child ui-view to an element instead of an attribute. So <ui-view></ui-view> instead of the div. I think it's a bug in angular.